Problems removing tub drain flange/basket
My wife and I had a bathroom remodeled a few years ago, and it appears that no plumber's putty was put between the drain flange/basket and the tub, so with the stopper properly closed, I can tell that water slowly leaks out between the flange and the tub.
Surprisingly, there is no evidence of any water damage, despite the considerable amount of water that has cumulatively leaked around the flange, so I'm assuming that water somehow made its way into the drain assembly.
I got a drain removal tool and turned it with a wrench, and the flange seemed to be loosening nicely until it began to pop back down one thread after every revolution.  Every subsequent effort on my part to free the flange has failed.  My best guess is that something about the flange is under tension, and as the flange rides up the very last thread, it gets pulled back down as soon as it passes the end of the last thread.
The following picture shows the furthest I've been able to unscrew the flange:

There is probably enough clearance for me to wrap some plumber's putty under the flange, and tighten it back down, but the thread popping has me concerned that something is amiss with the way the flange is connected to the drain assembly.
I know there are many kinds of drain stoppers, but it sounds like most drain flanges are standard, and I haven't come across any comments from other people describing what I'm experiencing.  By the way, this is an American Standard tub, and the drain flange and stopper came with the tub, if I recall correctly.
I would appreciate any suggestions of things that I could try, or hypotheses about what might be keeping the drain flange from unscrewing further, or guidance on whether I can safely apply the putty and close everything back up or whether I may have compromised my drain assembly in some way.

If you can get plumbers putty under the flange, do it and screw the flange back in.  Check for leaks and if there are none count your blessings.   I'm thinking the fitting may be cross threaded, but that is just a guess.

Thanks @RMDman.  I'm pretty sure the fitting is not cross-threaded, because all the rest of the unscrewing felt very normal.  But how would I check for leaks, since in my case there is no access to underside of the tub?  I could fill the tub to a point, leave the stopper in, and see if the water level drops in a one hour period, but if it doesn't, there could potentially still be a leak when the stopper is not engaged.

Make access. You'd need it to replace this anyway. If you just need to see for now, borescope access is relatively easy. A removable access panel is the proper and ideal solution.

I ended up contacting the original remodeler, who is going to come look at the problem.  By email he agreed that the described behavior didn't make sense.
